# Как передать char** внутрь сишной функции?

Tags: c++, c

api выглядит вот так:

```
void foo(char** outStrings);
```

нужно подать char**. Естественно вся работа с памятью ложиться на вызывающую сторону. И вот вопрос, как это делать?

Можно написать raii класс для простоты.

```
class Strings {
public:
    explicit String(size_t count, size_t stringSize) {
        data = new char*[count];
        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            data_ [i] = new char[stringSize + 1];
    }
    ~Strings() // деструткор все удалит
};
```

и использовать его вот так, точно зная, что деструктор вызовется и не будет мемориликов

```
Strings stringList(14,255);
foo(stringList.data());
```

А можно ли каким то образом передать внутрь той функции какойнибудь `std::vector<std::string>>` ? ну или сделать это какнить более "модерн" (под модерн я понимаю более современную интерпритацию плюсов... скажем ,например,  без оператора new)?

Кто решал такие задачи, поделитесь опытом

Comment: Ваша функция никак не знает о том, как именно ее вызывает и о том, что есть какие то объекты. Что делать? смирится, написать обертку вокруг foo, которая будет принимать нужный объект.

Comment: @KoVadim, я все таки написал код, который не делает ниодного new явно

Comment: я тоже так могу. например маллок позвать:) или на стеке выделить. Но не зная поведения функции `foo(char**)` я бы делал это аккуратно.

Comment: ну маллок тоже выделяет память и надо ее очищать путем вызова free или realloc, Я сделал обертку над char** внутри vector <char*> , где каждый char* ссылается на string, который имеет задаваемый размер. Везде в с++ надо быть аккуратней. :D

Comment: как я писал выше, мы не знаем, как там устроена функция. Вполне возможно, что  она тоже хочет менять размер, и тогда Вашей схеме будет очень плохо.

Comment: нет нет нет, все правильно. ей просто указатели под которых выделена память и все. дальше она их только возвращает

Answer (score -1):

А причём тут классы, векторы и всё прочее из плюсов? Описание char ** пришло из чистого С и означает массив символьных массивов. Как то так:

```
int j;
char *array[20];

for (j=0; j<20; j++) array[j] = (char *) malloc(256);

foo(array);
```

Comment: затем чтобы не управлять памятью вот так , как тут написано, чтобы не было утечек памяти. Поэтому я и обернул в отдельный класс

Comment: @Aptem_f - "не управлять памятью вот так , как тут"   - Удачи!